# Manage incoming Call with 2 sdk (CALL KIT & VoIP SDK) simultaneously?

Tags: ios

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Intents/Intents.h>
#import <CallKit/CallKit.h>
#import <PushKit/PushKit.h>

#pragma mark - PKPushRegistryDelegate

- (void)pushRegistry:(nonnull PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(nonnull PKPushCredentials *)pushCredentials forType:(nonnull PKPushType)type {
   if ([pushCredentials.token length] == 0) {
      NSLog(@"VoIP token NULL..");
   }
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(PKPushType)type
{
   NSString *uuidString = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"UUID"];
   NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
   NSString *phoneNumber = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"PhoneNumber"];
   CallViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallViewController"];
   viewController.number = phoneNumber;
   viewController.incoming = YES;
   viewController.callId = uuid;
   UIViewController *mainViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
   [mainViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#import "CallManager.h"
#import <CallKit/CallKit.h>
#import <CallKit/CXError.h>
@interface CallManager () <CXProviderDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CXProvider *provider;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallController *callController;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSUUID *currentCall;

@end

@implementation CallManager

+ (CallManager*)shaaredInstance {
    static CallManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[CallManager alloc] init];
        [sharedInstance provider];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)reportIncomingCallForUUID:(NSUUID*)uuid phoneNumber:(NSString*)phoneNumber {
    CXCallUpdate *update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    update.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:phoneNumber];
    __weak CallManager *weakSelf = self;
    [self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:uuid update:update completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            weakSelf.currentCall = uuid;
        } else {
            if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callDidFail)]) {
                [self.delegate callDidFail];
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (void)startCallWithPhoneNumber:(NSString*)phoneNumber {
    CXHandle *handle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:phoneNumber];
    self.currentCall = [NSUUID new];
    CXStartCallAction *startCallAction = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.currentCall handle:handle];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] init];
    [transaction addAction:startCallAction];
    [self requestTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)endCall {
    CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.currentCall];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] init];
    [transaction addAction:endCallAction];
    [self requestTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)holdCall:(BOOL)hold {
    CXSetHeldCallAction *holdCallAction = [[CXSetHeldCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.currentCall onHold:hold];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] init];
    [transaction addAction:holdCallAction];
    [self requestTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)requestTransaction:(CXTransaction*)transaction {
    [self.callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
            if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callDidFail)]) {
                [self.delegate callDidFail];
            }
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Getters

- (CXProvider*)provider {
    if (!_provider) {
        CXProviderConfiguration *configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"IP-PBX"];
        configuration.supportsVideo = YES;
        configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1;
        configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@(CXHandleTypePhoneNumber)];
        _provider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];
        [_provider setDelegate:self queue:nil];
    }
    return _provider;
}

- (CXCallController*)callController {
    if (!_callController) {
        _callController = [[CXCallController alloc] init];
    }
    return _callController;
}

#pragma mark - CXProviderDelegate

- (void)providerDidReset:(CXProvider *)provider {
}

// Called when the provider has been fully created and is ready to send actions and receive updates
- (void)providerDidBegin:(CXProvider *)provider {
}

// If provider:executeTransaction:error: returned NO, each perform*CallAction method is called sequentially for each action in the transaction
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performStartCallAction:(CXStartCallAction *)action {
    //todo: configure audio session
    //todo: start network call
    [self.provider reportOutgoingCallWithUUID:action.callUUID startedConnectingAtDate:nil];
    [self.provider reportOutgoingCallWithUUID:action.callUUID connectedAtDate:nil];

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callDidAnswer)]) {
        [self.delegate callDidAnswer];
    }
    [action fulfill];
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
    //todo: configure audio session
    //todo: answer network call
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callDidAnswer)]) {
       [self.delegate callDidAnswer];
    }
    [action fulfill];
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performEndCallAction:(CXEndCallAction *)action {
    //todo: stop audio
    //todo: end network call
    self.currentCall = nil;
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callDidEnd)]) {
        [self.delegate callDidEnd];
    }
   [action fulfill];
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action {
    if (action.isOnHold) {
        //todo: stop audio

    } else {
        //todo: start audio
    }
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callDidHold:)]) {
        [self.delegate callDidHold:action.isOnHold];
    }
    [action fulfill];
}
```

I am using Call Kit in VOIP application (using ABTO VoIP SDK too). But I want to merge my VoiP App call history to my iPHONE recent tab. I added Call kit in my project everything was fine I am getting VoIP app call history to my iPhone recent tab. But I am facing issues while calling once I do incoming or outgoing calls I am getting callkit default screen  which lead the incoming call on hold and outgoing to. Would there any way to manage callkit default screen? Would it be possible to manage two SDK at the same time??? I am using pushkit too..
Please help me to resolve this issue????

Whenever I am getting incoming call I am facing 2 calling screen one from Voip SDK and one from Call kit.. I want to manage that default screen